# Proving that if $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$ then $c < a + b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, proof-writing, triangles

I am having some trouble in proving a conjecture that occurred to me some time ago, based on the Pythagorean theorem.

If, for a non-degenerate triangle, $$c^2 = a^2 + b^2$$
Then can the following be proven?
$$c < a + b$$

Is this statement always true?

Comment: This is not true for degenerate triangles (e.g. $a=0$), so I assume you are asking if it can be proven for non-degenerate triangles, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: That's the triangle inequality, and holds true for all (non-degenerate) triangles, not just the right ones.

Comment: @Typhon it look's like it is a first. although i am not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $c^2=a^2+b^2<a^2+2ab+b^2=(a+b)^2$, therefore, by taking squares and noting that $a,b,c$ are positive, we obtain $c<a+b$.

Comment: The first inequality only holds if $a,b \neq 0$, however that case was excluded in a comment to the original question above.

Comment: Correct. That was my comment and I even stated again in this answer that $a,b,c>0$.

Answer (score 4):

Assume $c\ge a+b$, then we have $c^2\ge (a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2>a^2+b^2$. We arrived at a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

$a,b,c>0$ are the side lengths of a right triangle ($a,b$ the legs, $c$ the hypotenuse) **iff** $a^2+b^2=c^2$, by the (converse) Pythagorean theorem or by the cosine theorem.
 A right triangle is a triangle, hence its sides fulfill the triangle inequality $a+b > c$.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your doubt is:

> does a triple $(a,b,c)$ of ***positive*** numbers with $c^2=a^2+b^2$ also satisfy $c<a+b$, so that the three numbers are the sides of a triangle?

In particular, does a Pythagorean triple define a (right) triangle?

Indeed, the other two conditions, namely $a<b+c$ and $b<a+c$, are obviously satisfied because from $c^2=a^2+b^2$ we immediately get $c>a$ and $c>b$.

Also the third condition holds:
$$
c^2=a^2+b^2<a^2+2ab+b^2=(a+b)^2
$$
Note where the positivity assumption is applied.

More generally, suppose $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\tau$, where $-1<\tau<1$ (the cosine law should come to mind). Then
$$
c^2=a^2+2ab+b^2-2ab(1+\tau)=(a+b)^2-2ab(1+\tau)<(a+b)^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

For all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ we have $a^2 + b^2 < (a+b)^2 \implies \sqrt{a^2+b^2} < a+b$. If $c^2$ is defined to be $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$, then we have $c < a+b$. This also explains why the triangle cannot be degenerate, i.e. $a = 0$ or $b = 0$, in order for statement to be true.

Comment: Could you please explain how one fact leads to the other?

Comment: $a^2 + b^2 < (a+b)^2$ because $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ and we know that $a,b > 0$. So $2ab > 0$ therefore the inequality holds for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.